# Image is not displaying sequentially with a delay function

Tags: javascript, html

Code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="canvasContainer">
            <canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="520"></canvas>
            </div>
        <script src="image.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
//------------------------------
const gcCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  gcCanvas.width = 600;
  gcCanvas.height = 300;

const gcContext = gcCanvas.getContext('2d');

const gcBackgroundImage = new Image();
const gcBackgroundWidth = gcCanvas.width;
let glBackgroundHeight; 

const gcCarImage = new Image();
const gcCarImageWidth = 40; 
const gcCarImageHeight = 100; 
let glCarTopLeftX; 
let glCarTopLeftY; 

let glDegrees = 0;
let glArrowFlag = false;
//------------------------------
//++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
//------------------------------
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (ev) => 
  {
    gcBackgroundImage.onload = function ()
    {
      gcCarImage.onload = function () 
      {
        const cAspectRatio = gcBackgroundImage.naturalWidth / gcBackgroundImage.naturalHeight;
        glBackgroundHeight = gcCanvas.height = gcBackgroundWidth / cAspectRatio; 
        gcContext.drawImage(gcBackgroundImage, 0, 0, gcBackgroundWidth, glBackgroundHeight); 
        glCarTopLeftX = gcBackgroundWidth / 2 - gcCarImageWidth / 2; 
        glCarTopLeftY = glBackgroundHeight / 2 - gcCarImageHeight / 2; 
        gcContext.drawImage(gcCarImage, glCarTopLeftX, glCarTopLeftY, gcCarImageWidth, gcCarImageHeight);
      }
      gcCarImage.src = "Car.jpg"; 
    }
    gcBackgroundImage.src = "Streets.jpg";
  }
)//document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'
//------------------------------
//------------------------------
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", e =>
  {
    let lRenderFlag = false;
    e.preventDefault();
    switch(e.key) {
      case 's':
        glDegrees = 0;
        for (let ii = 0; ii < 360; ii++) {
          glDegrees = ii;
          let lCarCenterX = glCarTopLeftX + gcCarImageWidth / 2;
          let lCarCenterY = glCarTopLeftY + gcCarImageHeight / 2;  
          fRender(lCarCenterX, lCarCenterY, glDegrees);
          fSleep(1000);
        } 
        break;
    }
  }
)//document.body.addEventListener("keydown"
//------------------------------
//------------------------------
function fSleep(num) 
{
  let now = new Date();
  let stop = now.getTime() + num;
  while(true) {
      now = new Date();
      if(now.getTime() > stop) return;
  }
}//fSleep
//------------------------------
//------------------------------
function fRender(lCarCenterX, lCarCenterY, glDegrees) 
{
  gcContext.clearRect(0, 0, gcCanvas.width, gcCanvas.height);
  gcContext.drawImage(gcBackgroundImage, 0, 0, gcBackgroundWidth, glBackgroundHeight);
  let lRadians = Math.PI / 180 * glDegrees;
  gcContext.translate(lCarCenterX, lCarCenterY);
  gcContext.rotate(lRadians);
  gcContext.drawImage(gcCarImage, -gcCarImageWidth / 2, -gcCarImageHeight / 2, gcCarImageWidth, gcCarImageHeight);
  gcContext.rotate(-lRadians);
  gcContext.translate(-lCarCenterX, -lCarCenterY);    
}//fRender
//------------------------------
```

This code is to have a car rotate on a background image.  Entering "s" should start the rotation sequence.

To slow the rotation, a fSleep" function has been added (delays 1 sec):

When running code, the car image never changes.  Putting a Breakpoint on the fSleep function does display the car rotating with every F5.

--
The car and background images — Car.jpg => https://snipboard.io/ptkWjJ.jpg — Streets.jpg => https://snipboard.io/4YgDaf.jpg.

The images combined — https://snipboard.io/C8LZXu.jpg

Comment: Your delay function keeps the CPU core busy, not allowing anything else (such as a page render!) to run. Use asynchronous code instead!

Comment: When doing animation or anything time based, think in terms of events as opposed to delays. Here's when setInterval and setTimeout come into play. Research "game loop" or "animation loop".

Comment: CherryDT, I'm interested in an asynchronous code example.

Comment: Don't ever use a spinner loop: JS is not multi-threaded (unless you use things like workers), it's merely asynchronous. Use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) if you need something to happen "some time later".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove "function fSleep(num)".  Replace case 's': contents with:

```
case 's':
  let lCarCenterX = glCarTopLeftX + gcCarImageWidth / 2;
  let lCarCenterY = glCarTopLeftY + gcCarImageHeight / 2;
  let lRotate = () => {
    fRender(lCarCenterX, lCarCenterY, glDegrees);
    if (glDegrees < 360) {
      glDegrees += 1;
      //setTimeout() sets a timer which executes a function after the timer expires 
      setTimeout(lRotate, 2000 / 360);
    }
  };
  glDegrees = 0;
  lRotate();
  break;
```